# Cannot acces a specific webpage from one computer, but I can access from different devices. All are connected to the same wifi network. Why?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, dns, git

I'm trying to access a git domain eg: "git.company.com" and I can access it from only one of the two computers. The domain is online and both computers have internet access. I need to be able to connect to the repo from both.

**Thing I've tried on the non-working computer**:

1. Connect to a different wifi network and access the address on
   browser.
2. Use a different browser (first chrome then edge)
3. Ping the domain name(Request timeout, different ip shown from what working pc shows when it pings too)
4. Open in browser the ip address shown by working pc in the non-working computer (sends me to a different subdomain of the same domain eg:"start.company.com" instead of "git.company.com")
5. Change the DNS server in non-working pc (nothing changed)
6. Reset firewall setttings (still not being able to connect)
7. Access from a virtual machine hosted in non-working pc (surprisingly
       it works)

I can also access the website from different devices (phones etc), just that computer does not connect for some reason.

Both computers have the same OS (windows 10). I'm not the owner of the domain I'm trying to connect, thus I cannot make changes on it. No VPN service is running in either pc.

Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Could be a DNS caching issue, try running `ipconfig /flushdns` from a command prompt.

Comment: I just tried that too. Sadly, it's not working.

Comment: Check yours `hosts` file.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks! you were right, for some reason the host file had a different ip address mapped to the domain name.

Comment: Great. I'll write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'm trying to access git.company.com and I can access it from only one of two computers.

Given all of the troubleshooting you have already performed you should also check your `hosts` file.

This has been confirmed by the OP in a comment as the cause of the problem:

> [you were right, for some reason the host file had a different ip address mapped to the domain name](https://superuser.com/questions/1537158/cannot-acces-a-specific-webpage-from-one-computer-but-i-can-access-from-differe?noredirect=1#comment2334235_1537158)